# Commenting code out/in IntelliJ IDEA german keyboard

Tags: intellij-idea, comments

After updated IntelliJ IDEA to 2017.1, I can not any more comment out/in code. I am using a german keyboard and until yet i could use a workaround to comment code in/out with the shortcut "CMD" + "-" but now it isn't working any more. The shortcuts "CMD" + "/" isn't working.

Any ideas to solve this problem on a german keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either reassign this action to the working shortcut in the [Keymap preferences](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html) or use [this workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165950#comment=27-2053321):

> 1. [Install](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html) JB SDK Bintray Downloader plugin. You can find it in the plugin repository right in the IDE settings.
> 2. Find the action "Get JB SDK from BinTray" (On Mac you can use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> shortcut to find the action by name)
> 3. Choose appropriate Runtime version (build **795** or later)
> 4. Download it
> 5. Install it
> 6. Restart IntelliJ IDEA (it should happen automatically)
> 7. Check the IDE About dialog to be sure that the IDE is bootstrapped with the desired version of the runtime
>
> To enable OpenJDK behavior go to Help | **Edit Custom Properties**, add the following property into the file:
>
> `com.jetbrains.use.old.keyevent.processing=true`

Comment: The "Cmd + A" (cmd+shift+a) did work on my Mac, but the rest works fine. Note that I couldn't get the action "Get JB SDK from BinTray", I had to restart after having downloaded the JetBrain OpenSDK.